# How can I use regex to convert Uppercase text to lowercase text in combination with a look-ahead and look-behind

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

In the context of an XML file, I want to use the XML tags in a positive look-behind and positive look-ahead to convert a value to lowercase.

BEFORE:

```
<CONDITION NAME="ABC-DEF-GHI" DATE="DATE">
```

AFTER:

```
<CONDITION NAME="abc-def-ghi" DATE="DATE">
```

Pattern's tried from other questions/regex wiki that don't work.

1.

```
FIND:    
(?<=(<CONDITION NAME="))(.+)(?=(" DATE="DATE"))
REPLACE:
\L0
```

2. 

```
FIND:    
(?<=(<CONDITION NAME=".*))(\w)(?=(.*" DATE="DATE"))
REPLACE:
\L$1
```

Using VS Code 1.62.1
MAC OS Darwin x64 19.6.0

Comment: Why are you using capture groups inside look arround?

Comment: I used them to try and make it more readable.

Comment: honestly I would just parse that as json, and then change the values as you wish, and then make it json again.  it's only a line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any capture groups if yo want to use lookarounds at the left and right side.

Instead of using `.+` which is a broad match and can match too much, you can use a negated character class `[^"]+` to match any character except a double quote, or you can use `[\w-]+` to match 1 or more word characters or a hyphen:

```
(?<=<CONDITION NAME=")[^"]+(?=" DATE="DATE")
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QE6doy/1)

Replace with the full match using `$0`

```
\L$0
```

---

Another option is to use 2 capture groups with a single lookahead as lookarounds can be expensive, and replace with `$1\L$2`

```
(<CONDITION NAME=")([\w-]+)(?=" DATE="DATE")
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you make the other groups non-capturing:

```
(?<=(?:<CONDITION NAME="))(.+)(?=(?:" DATE="DATE"))
```

Or leave out the inner `()` altogether:

```
(?<=<CONDITION NAME=")(.+)(?=" DATE="DATE")
```

Or use `$2` as replacement. Everything between standard `()` becomes a captured group, no matter where in the expression they are.

And be careful with `.+`, in this case `[^"]+` is a much safer choice.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern 2 works. The replace value just needs to change from
\L$1 -> \L$2

Pattern 1 could also be used with \L$2 as the replace value.

This pattern works:
FIND:
(?<=(<CONDITION NAME=".*))(\w)(?=(.*" DATE="DATE"))
REPLACE:
\L$2

Comment: Same question: Why are you using capture groups inside look arround?